# Accessing standard VBA word enumerations

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm new to VBA. Some tutorials tell me to use enumeration constants such as wdOrientLandscape and wdRowHeightExactly (to change page orientation and make row height 'exact' respectively). However, when debugging, I can see that the value of these constants is *Empty* and they don't 'work' as expected.

Do I need to do something special to access these constants e.g. add a reference or something?

I'm creating a Word document from an Excel macro.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure you have the correct references in **Tools > References...**

Comment: In particular you want the Microsoft Word Object Library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within Excel (or any automation client) the enumerations belonging to the Word object model are not exposed if you use Late Binding (`CreateObject("Word.Application")`).

If you early bind by adding a reference they become visible.

If you add `Option Explicit` to the top of you code modules (or select Require Variable Declarations from the VBA editor options) you will receive a compile time warning if you attempt to use something that's not declared/unavailable

In your particular case, you would want to add the Microsoft Word Object Library to your references. If you choose to early bind. This can be done by going to Tools>>References and checking the appropriate box.

Comment: Thank you - this really helped. I did not know about 'early binding' and 'late binding' before.

I had before:

`Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Dim objDoc As Object
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add`

Now I have:

`Dim objWord As Word.Application
Set objWord = New Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add`

and added the reference to Word as suggested. Now the constants work and so does autocomplete on Word-related objects! Thanks everyone.